# Thread dateformatter in Swift 1.2

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, nsthread

As for performance reasons I've used this global variable for my dateformatters. After updating to Swift 1.2 this one is no longer working and gave me an segmentation fault 11 in merging swiftmodule.

```
let kCachedDateFormatterKey:String = "kCachedDateFormatterKey"
var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter {
    get {
        var threadDictionary = NSThread.currentThread().threadDictionary
        var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter? = threadDictionary.objectForKey(kCachedDateFormatterKey) as? NSDateFormatter

        if dateFormatter == nil {
            dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            var nlLocale:NSLocale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "nl_NL")
            dateFormatter?.locale = nlLocale
            dateFormatter?.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
            threadDictionary.setObject(dateFormatter!, forKey: kCachedDateFormatterKey)
        }
        return dateFormatter!
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to use a threaded dateformatter in Swift 1.2. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that NSDateFormatter *is thread-safe* on all iOS and OS X versions that can be used with Swift. See the "THREAD SAFETY" notes in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/.

Comment: Ok, that will leave me up with a singleton, solving this problem. Thanks for clarifying!